# Autofocus feature on the popovers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI ReactJS :does material UI support any autofocus feature on the popovers.

I want to set the focus on the popover, as soon as the material UI popover opens.

Answer (score 2):

MaterialUI Popovers inherit the Modal API. Supposedly the `disableAutoFocus` property allows NOT focusing on Popover/Modal content, however I also am experiencing it NEVER focusing in the first place.

https://material-ui.com/api/modal/

Answer (score 0):

On what do you want to set the focus ?

The "autoFocus" property should be set on some Popover content childs.

For example, we use the "autoFocus" property of Material-UI TextField for this : 
https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: I have  `<a>` tags in my popover ..so as soon as I open my popover I need a focus on that. I knew that textfield has this property but since I don't have it in my popover, I  explicitly tried to focus on it using `ref ` and .focus().

But now the problem is that after closing the popover the tab order changes ,i.e. instead of shifting to the next element after the popover icon, on clicking TAB key,  the tab flow starts again from the beginning.

may be because the popover is not in the natural tab flow.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to set the focus on a <a> tag ? If it really is what you want, you will have to implement the focus prop/state yourself, as there is no "autofocus" link component in material-ui. You should implement something like a "FocusableLink" component maybe... Anyway, the problem is not with the Popover component, but with it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `autoFocus` property to the first form element in your popover.

```
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <input type="text" autoFocus />
        <Typography className={classes.typography}>
          The content of the Popover.
        </Typography>
      </Popover>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/qbx44l?file=demo.js